# Burninate [keycloak-2.0.0]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[keycloak-2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keycloak-2.0.0) is much too specific. The four questions having this tag are also tagged with [keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keycloak). There are still few questions with [keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keycloak), so I would rather go with a single tag and specify the version being used in the question itself.

Comment: You are among the 10 top answers in the keycloak tag so we trust you!, if I were you I would just remove the tag, since only 4 questions (cv what need to be cv:ed) and carry on (the tag will get auto deleted later)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do it, didn't know about the feature of the tags getting removed! Thanks

Comment: Great, have fun, when done wait a day, then you can flag this meta post for moderator, so they can status-completed it.